# R: merging data tables based on a custom rule

Tags: r, join

I am trying to merge two data tables with a rule I am not able to traslate into R code.

Let us assume that we are dealing with customers: each customer can fall within one or more categories, and each category can buy a certain subset of products.

Then I have two data frames to merge, i.e.

```
df1
customer   category
Anthony    X
Anthony    Y
Beatrix    Y
Charles    Z

df2
product    category
item1      X
item2      Y
item3      Y
item3      Z

df3 = required merge of (df1, df2)
customer   product
Anthony    item1
Anthony    item2
Anthony    item3
Beatrix    item2
Beatrix    item3
Charles    item3
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, I understand it as joining all products associated with each category to each customer's categories. The following will work in this case:

Generate data:

```
df1 <- read.table(header = T, text = "customer   category
Anthony    X
Anthony    Y
Beatrix    Y
Charles    Z")

df2 <- read.table(header = T, text = "product    category
item1      X
item2      Y
item3      Y
item3      Z")
```

dplyr package solution:

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2) %>% select(-category)

  customer product
1  Anthony   item1
2  Anthony   item2
3  Anthony   item3
4  Beatrix   item2
5  Beatrix   item3
6  Charles   item3
```

**Edit** alternative solution from base package (suggested by lmo):

```
merge(df1, df2, by="category")[-1]

  customer product
1  Anthony   item1
2  Anthony   item2
3  Anthony   item3
4  Beatrix   item2
5  Beatrix   item3
6  Charles   item3
```

Comment: You might as well add the base R method: `merge(df1, df2, by="category")[-1]`.

Comment: @lmo Thanks for the suggestion. I've incorporated it. :)

Comment: @Z.Lin Thank you!